# Checking Network Connection on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm a Javascript novice and a PhoneGap Newbie...

I know this question has been posted in numerous ways, but I just can't get the basics to work here. I've tried to copy other answers and I just can't seem to get anywhere with the Network-Information plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

At this point I really just want a barebones example of checking for a network connection at launch (onDeviceReady), and then a way to check again to see if the user's device has changed from online to offline and vice versa (seen some people suggest setTimeout for this piece).

After some testing, it seems like my navigator.connection.type check is not firing.

I have the org.apache.cordova.network-inforamtion installed. Please help... I've spent about a week pulling my hair out here. :)

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ga.js">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        // 
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            checkConnection();
        }

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }

        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

        function onOffline() {
            // Handle the offline event
            alert('Offline');
        }

        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

        function onOnline() {
            // Handle the online event
            alert('Online');
        }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Install network plugin org.apache.cordova.network-information and try the following:-

document.addEventListener("resume", getintoForeground, false);  

function getintoForeground(){
var ntwk = CheckConnection();

if (ntwk) {
    alert("Network available");
}else{
    alert("Network  not available");
}
}

function CheckConnection(){
    if( !navigator.network ){
                navigator.network = window.top.navigator.network;
    }
    return ( (navigator.network.connection.type === "none" || navigator.network.connection.type === null || 
                navigator.network.connection.type === "unknown" ) ? false : true );
    }
```